# ArcPad APL - enforcing unique values

Tags: arcpad

At my work we use ArcPad to collect inspection point data. One of the fields is SITEID that is manually entered by a staff member (its a combination of their initials and a number (eg ST01). I would like to add an event handler (I'm using OnChange in my code) to my APL file that checks if the SITEID already exists. Im finding it very difficult to debug in ArcStudio so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is my APL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ArcPad>
<LAYER name="SoilSurvey_InspectionSitesSimple_UTM10N" transparency="1">
    <FORMS>
        <EDITFORM name="EDITFORM" caption="Soil Inspection Sites" width="160" height="150" color="Blue" picturepagevisible="true" attributespagevisible="true" symbologypagevisible="true" geographypagevisible="true" required="false">
            <PAGE name="SiteDetails" caption="Site Details">
                <LABEL name="slblSiteID" x="3" y="3" width="35" height="10" caption="Site ID" tooltip="" group="true" border="false"/>
                <LABEL name="slblDate" x="3" y="18" width="35" height="10" caption="Date" tooltip="" group="true" border="false"/>
                <EDIT name="txtSiteID" x="45" y="1" width="75" height="12" defaultvalue="" **onchange="Call CheckSITEID"** tooltip="" tabstop="true" border="true" required="true" field="SITEID" uppercase="true" multiline="true"/>
                <DATETIME name="dtDate" x="45" y="17" width="75" height="12" defaultvalue="Now ()" tooltip="" tabstop="true" border="true" field="DATE_"/>
                <LABEL name="slblComments" x="3" y="35" width="35" height="10" caption="Comments" tooltip="" group="true" border="false"/>
                <EDIT name="txtComments" x="3" y="48" width="100" height="50" defaultvalue="" tooltip="" tabstop="true" border="true" field="Comments" uppercase="true" multiline="true"/>
            </PAGE>
        </EDITFORM>
    </FORMS>
    <SYMBOLOGY>
        <SIMPLELABELRENDERER visible="false" field="" rotationfield="" expression="" language="">
            <TEXTSYMBOL fontcolor="Black" font="Arial" fontsize="8" vertalignment="bottom" rtl="false" fontstyle="regular"/>
        </SIMPLELABELRENDERER>
        <SIMPLERENDERER>
            <SIMPLEMARKERSYMBOL color="76,230,0" width="3" outlinewidth="1"/>
        </SIMPLERENDERER>
    </SYMBOLOGY>
    <METADATA/>
    <QUERY where=""/>
    <FIELDHISTORY>
        <FIELDS>
            <FIELD name="X"/>
            <FIELD name="Y"/>
            <FIELD name="SITEID" value="3"/>
            <FIELD name="Z"/>
            <FIELD name="DATE_"/>
            <FIELD name="ID"/>
            <FIELD name="Comments" value=""/>
        </FIELDS>
    </FIELDHISTORY>
    </LAYER>

<SCRIPT language="VBScript">
    Sub CheckSITEID
    Dim objEditForm, InputSite, ExistingRec
    Set  InputSite = ThisEvent.Object.Value 
    Dim objRS
    Set objRS = Map.Selectionlayer.Records
    If (objRS.RecordCount > 0) Then
        objRS.Movefirst
        While Not objRS.EOF
            Set ExistingRec = objRS.Fields("SITEID").Value
            If InputSite = ExistingRec Then
            ThisEvent.Result = False
            ThisEvent.MessageText  = "SITEID ALREADY EXISTS"
            End If
            objRS.MoveNext
         Wend
    End If
    End Sub
</SCRIPT language="VBScript">
</ArcPad>
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?  Have you tried checking both the InputSite and ExistingRec values within a messagebox to see what they are?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors but I still can add multiple points with the same siteid so its not working. How do I add a message box? is it ThisEven.MessageText = "InputSite:"& InputSite  ?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help?
I needed something similiar..
I put this on the onValidate event

```
Dim pole, existing, record
Set pole = Map.Layers("Pole").Records
record = ThisEvent.Object.Value

pole.MoveFirst
Do Until pole.EOF
     existing = pole.Fields("IMAGE").Value
     If existing = record Then
        ThisEvent.Result = False
        ThisEvent.MessageText = "This image already exists"
     ElseIf record = "" Then
        ThisEvent.Result = True
     End If
     pole.MoveNext
Loop
```